# How do I secure a Java REST service using Drupal?

Tags: security, drupal, authentication, rest, jakarta-ee

I am creating a web application that uses the Drupal 7 Content Management System.  The web pages heavily use JQuery and AJAX.

The AJAX calls hit REST services, which are actually implemented using JAVA.  Apache is running Drupal 7 and is configured to pass any calls to the REST urls through to the Java EE server (Jboss AS7).  Everything is over SSL.

I need to Authorise and Authenticate calls to the REST services, and access the username or ID of the person currently logged-in to Drupal from the Java app.  The question is... how...

As the AJAX calls are made to the same Apache server (rather than to a separate server etc), everything happens within the same http session, so I'm hoping this will be quite easy.

Things I've thought-of:

- Configure a java security interceptor that calls a custom (locally
  accessed only) drupal service that somehow reads the session id and
  returns the logged-in username
- create a "dumb" drupal REST service to act as a gateway for all of my REST calls, which authorises/ authenticates then injects the username before passing-through to the Java backend service
- The article at https://lists.wisc.edu/read/messages?id=7777296#7777296 made me wonder if I could get-away with calling a Drupal service (just at the start of each Java service session) that takes a Drupal sessionID and returns the current user and his roles.  I could configure it in my Java service so it would reperform this call every x seconds or y calls to check for role changes or logouts.

How does everyone else do it? This must be a common problem to solve isn't it?  If not, what do you do instead to securely access authenticated services over AJAX?  I'd rather not introduce a second user control process in addition to Drupal unless it's unavoidable.  DRY :)

Thank you - this has me stumped!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what you are doing and trying to keep things as simple as possible, I would go for a variation of the first option. This is basically what the current [node.js](http://drupal.org/project/nodejs) module does although it does it with unique authorization tokens. The workflow is something like this:

1. When a logged in user loads a page, a unique token is generated and stored in the Drupal database and sent to the browser
2. When the browser goes to connect to the node.js server it sends the auth token along with the request
3. The node.js server, upon receiving the request with token for the first time, will connect to a web service on the Drupal site and verify that the token is valid and send back any info about the user, and what roles/etc they have.
4. The node.js server then stores this internally for future requests, so that it doesn't have to ping the Drupal site for each request.
5. When a user logs out of Drupal, Drupal makes a direct request to the node.js server asking it to delete the token for that user.

Sounds like basically swapping your java app for node.js this should be pretty doable, with the advantage that it can scale well if you split this to multiple servers in the future.

Comment: That makes sense.  Would it be possible to use the session variable stored in the headers or cookie as the unique token, to remove the need for the an extra token?